Getting HTTP 429 error scraping archive.is (and other sites) from AWS. Whats the proper way to set up network-traffic so it appears non-AWS
So, when I curl from an EC2 Instance or a lambda, I get a 429 error on the first try:
% curl -i http://archive.is/timegate/http://www.w3.org/TR/webarch/
HTTP/1.1 429 Too Many Requests
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2024 10:24:56 GMT
Server: nginx/1.9.2
Content-Type: text/html
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 26
Connection: keep-alive

But when I hit it from a local express.js (or local SAM lambda), it works perfectly.
I've tried using an elastic IP but that did nothing. Would a VPC somehow fix this? I feel like its because its coming from AWS IP addresses. And archive.is has, understandably, blacklisted all of AWS. I get that the whole reason they're doing this is to prevent bots. But this service will only scrape on demand (from human interaction) and in very limited quantities. Is there a correct way to make it look like traffic is NOT coming from AWS? Can I use my home/work-machine to host a server that I somehow set up in API Gateway or VPN or something so that my machine can be used as the scraping server? If you give me broad strokes, I can research more on my own.
This is the function (but really, all its doing is hitting that URL^):
import axios from 'axios';

type Request = {
  path: string;
  httpMethod: string;
  alias: string;
  input: {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    url: string;
  };
};

const headers = {
  Host: 'archive.is',
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0',
  Accept:
    'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/png,image/svg+xml,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br, zstd',
  Referer: 'https://archive.is/',
  Connection: 'keep-alive',
  Cookie:
    'tmr_lvid=8038ff6d405f75358c25363f2977ed47; tmr_lvidTS=1726213036055; domain_sid=cobs71VBpxbYREWytnErI%3A1726818293313; tmr_detect=0%7C1726891432364; _ga=GA1.2.661111166.1726891424',
  'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
  'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
  'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
  'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
  Priority: 'u=0, i',
};

export async function archivedArticle(request: Partial<Request>) {
  if (!request?.input?.url) {
    throw new Error('URL Requried');
  }

  // Testing Ish Out
  const timeGateUrl = `http://archive.is/timegate/${request.input.url}`;
  const timeGateRes = await axios.get(timeGateUrl, {headers});
  console.log(JSON.stringify({ data: timeGateRes.data }));
  return { ...request, timeGateRes };
}


